# Jsfiddle project shows in preview but not in result page

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, amcharts

Hi I edited the following amCharts map to showcase an interactive map timeline. I can view it in the previewer but not in the result page. Is there any way I can troubleshoot this? I am not getting any errors that I can find so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/curiousjazz77/1y9t6vm9/1/

Do you think I am locked out of the image being pulled from the amChart library?

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {
// let's generate the data for 50 slides
generateData();

// let's build the map
map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
map.pathToImages = "http://www.ammap.com/lib/3/images/";
//map.panEventsEnabled = true; // this line enables pinch-zooming and     dragging on touch devices
map.colorSteps = 50;
map.balloon.color = "#000000";
map.minValue = 0;
map.maxValue = 100000;
var dataProvider = {
    mapVar: AmCharts.maps.usaLow,
    getAreasFromMap: true,
    images: [ // let's add one image to display the year of the current slide
```

Comment: Hmm, I see it just fine in the Result pane. What browser/OS do you use?

Answer (score 4):

Load jsfiddle using HTTP and not HTTPS.

Your scripts are loaded using http and you load jsfiddle using https so, for security purposes, the content is blocked.

Replace `https` in the url by `http`

Comment: This is exactly what happened for us. Had to load the amcharts.com resources over HTTPS instead of HTTP since our application is using HTTPS. Worked like a charm.